# import data from web

Tags: web, import, ssis, last-modified

My requirement is to get the "created date" / "modified date" of a dataset on a web page into a .xls or .csv file.

The URL is: https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Agency-For-Healthcare-Research-And-Quality-Nationa/sdhm-um6i/about

From this web page, I would like to import created date which you can see on the right side using script task in SSIS.

I have tried using excel data -> import from web . It doesn't work!

It would be of great help if someone has any suggestions on this.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider explaining what the web page contains instead of linking to it (dead links could happen someday!)

Comment: The webpage is an **about** page, it contains all the data related to the dataset like description, author, created date, updated data, tags, etc. I would like to get the created date from this page.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing native to SSIS for parsing web pages like this. That said, I hope you like .NET coding.

I've done something similar with the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) Work through their documentation and examples to understand the basics of how to parse HTML with their library.

Once you have that settled, it's a simple matter of determining the path to the element(s) you desire. I have found the best approach to be open the page with Chrome, right click on the thing of interest and choose "Inspect Element". Expand fields until you get to the thing you're after and then right click in the inspector window and select `Copy XPath`

[image]

That results in the following xpath selector

```
//*[@id="aboutSection"]/div/div/div/div[1]/p[1]/span/span
```

I'd then use it in code like

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(this.html);
string createDate = string.Empty;
createDate = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id="aboutSection"]/div/div/div/div[1]/p[1]/span/span").InnerText.Trim();
```

You'll need to fiddle with the exact mechanics of the SelectSingleNode call but that's the general concept. You might also notice that you have an attribute data-rawdatetime with a value there. I'm guessing that's epoch date but if you can translate that to the presented value of "Oct 20, 2011", you might be better off as that numeric value won't be dependent upon regional settings.

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer definitely threw some light on how to proceed. I tried using `Dim src As String =system.net.DownloadString("URL")` to get the source code into a string and thereon by using string functions I could get the desired output.